# build istio/istio 1.6.0 from master - curl: (60) SSL certificate problem

Tags: curl, makefile, ssl-certificate, istio, envoyproxy

I try to build `istio/istio` from `master` use `make build`, according to https://github.com/istio/istio/wiki/Using-the-Code-Base .
When build-script try to download `istio-proxy`, `curl` exit with error code:

```
...
Downloading Envoy: curl -fLSs https://github.com/istio/proxy/releases/download/1.0.2/istio-proxy-1.0.2-macos.tar.gz to /work/out/darwin_amd64/release/envoy-1.0.2
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
...
```

I visited https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html , download last version `cacert.pem` and put to `/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem`.

After all I could download `istio-proxy-1.0.2-macos.tar.gz` manually (use `curl`)

```
curl -L https://github.com/istio/proxy/releases/download/1.0.2/istio-proxy-1.0.2-macos.tar.gz --output some-output-file
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   620  100   620    0     0   1383      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1383
100 7947k  100 7947k    0     0   631k      0  0:00:12  0:00:12 --:--:-- 1359k
```

,but error still occur during execution `make build`.

When use `curl` with `-k`(Allow insecure server connections when using SSL), get `You are being redirected.`:

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com/75322405/f13ffa80-b53b-11e8-9527-2a586cbda4ad?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20200304%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20200304T111428Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=300&amp;X-Amz-Signature=73a2788ecc120b520a6ddeb237b8bbd74a035f71e3aed8f5ee2de6f463abf3fc&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&amp;actor_id=0&amp;response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Distio-proxy-1.0.2-macos.tar.gz&amp;response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

**OS**: *macOS Catalina 10.15.1*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*tmp solution* **=>** add `-k` option  to

```
...
if command -v curl > /dev/null; then
    if curl --version | grep Protocols  | grep https > /dev/null; then
      DOWNLOAD_COMMAND='curl -kfLSs'
      return
...
```

to `bin/init.sh` **=>** wherever used `DOWNLOAD_COMMAND`, used insecure connection.

I know It's bad idea...